# Showing Querys in jtable

Tags: java, mysql, jtable

Hello im doing a project for my java class, in simple words i have to do a program that lets you make query by hand, like i put on a textbox example "select * from table" and it shows the results, second problem would be if  a delete, update or insert the program should auto execute a select sentence to show the results.

```
public class InfoCd extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTable table;
    private JTextField textQuery;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    InfoCd frame = new InfoCd();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
Connection conn=null;

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public InfoCd() {

        conn=sqliteConnection.dbConnector();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 753, 477);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBackground(SystemColor.activeCaption);
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JButton btnHacerConsulta = new JButton("Hacer Consulta");
        btnHacerConsulta.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    String query="'?'";
                    PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(query);
                    pst.setString(1, textQuery.getText());
                    ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
                    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                } catch (Exception e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        btnHacerConsulta.setBounds(112, 388, 169, 39);
        contentPane.add(btnHacerConsulta);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(0, 0, 737, 367);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane);

        table = new JTable();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

        textQuery = new JTextField();
        textQuery.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 11));
        textQuery.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        textQuery.setText("Escribir Consulta Aqui");
        textQuery.setToolTipText("");
        textQuery.setBounds(422, 388, 270, 39);
        contentPane.add(textQuery);
        textQuery.setColumns(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: when i put the querry on the textbox and click accept program crashes i belive this is not working
`String query="'?'";
                    PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(query);

                    pst.setString(1, textQuery.getText());

                    ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();

                    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                }`

Comment: `and click accept program crashes` - that tells us nothing. I would guess you get some kind of message. How would you expect an SQL statement consisting of a "?" would do anything? That is not how an SQL statement is used. In fact if you expect the user to type in the whole statement, then you should not even be using a PreparedStatement. It will be up to the user to format the statement correctly, which by the way is not a very good design. Basically the variable "query" needs to be assigned the text from the text field.

Comment: Is the assaignmet, how should i do it then?

Comment: A PreparedStatement is used when you pass parameters to the SQL. Since you won't be passing any parameters you can use use a `Statement`. So first get you code working with a hardcoded SQL statement. Once that works you just replace your hardcoded string with `textField.getText()`.

Comment: can you give me an example of how is that used?

Answer (score 0):

Normally the SQL would look something like:

```
String query = "Select * from TableName";
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
```

So if you want to do this dynamically with a query from a text field you just do:

```
String query = textField.getText();
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
```

So it is up to the user to type the proper SQL query into the text field.

Read the tutorial on [SQL Basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) for more information.

Comment: @Nycoh, glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so others know the problem has been solved.